# How to Compare 1 and 0 and are they equal? with using filereader

Tags: java

I'm trying to wraite a Java program that reads input in text file and compares 1s to 0s. The result is equal when the frequency of 1s are equal to the frequency of 0s.

Example:

Input.txt

> 1100
>   100
>   101
>   10

Output.txt

> Equal!
>   Not Equal!
>   Not Equal!
>   Equal

This is the code I'm working with:

```
package automata;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
     FileReader freader = new FileReader("Input.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(freader);
     try
{

    String s="";
    while((s = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++)
        {
            if(s.charAt(i) == '0') count++;
            else if(s.charAt(i) == '1') count--;
        }
        if(count == 0) System.out.print("Equal!\n");
        else System.out.print("Not Equal! \n");
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
            }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a *specific* problem? SO isn't really a Site where we'll just do your homework.

Comment: Jinx. Also: your question is really unclear, I can't even figure out which character in the input is compared against which given your example output.

Comment: import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
         FileReader freader = new FileReader("Input.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(freader);
                String strName = "";
                StringTokenizer st = null;
String[] strArray = new String[] {strName};
while((strName=br.readLine())!=null){
System.out.println(strArray[0]);
}
    }

}

Comment: Split the problems in two parts. 1. read a file line by line. 2. determine if a string contains the same number of 0s and 1s. When you have those two things working, it will be easy to combine them. Read the Java tutorial on IO. Read the javadoc of the class java.lang.String.

Comment: That is not done yet.. I don't what is the next step is..

Comment: Hopefully it's obvious the code is unbeatable as a comment. Please edit the question instead.

Comment: Leaving this closed as it's simply much too localized.

Answer (score 2):

That's how I'd do it.

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestFile
{
    public TestFile()
    {
        File inputFile = new File("input.txt"),
             outputFile = new File("output.txt");

        try
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
            String s;
            while((s = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                int count = 0;
                for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++)
                {
                    if(s.charAt(i) == '0') count++;
                    else if(s.charAt(i) == '1') count--;
                }
                if(count == 0) bw.append("Equal!\n");
                else bw.append("Not Equal! \n");
            }
            br.close();
            bw.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new TestFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very hard to say because it depends on how you implemented your program. Well let's say your project contains a class `TestFile`. Just use the code above, and create a file `input.txt` into your project folder, then run the program, it will create an `output.txt` file as wanted.

Comment: OH! Thank you very much for helping me... I've done editing your code. Instead of output in Txt file, I make it in Netbeans' output. Thank you very much again.. and now, time to sleep because it is already 12midnight here in Philippines.. =D

Comment: Nice. :) Don't hesitate to upvote and accept the answer if it helped you!

Comment: I want to vote but it requires 15 reputation.. I am new here so I don't know what are the rules here.

Comment: Ah you're right, that's because of reputation, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you iterate over every character of each line,

- you could count the ones or zeros and compare the result to the half of the length on the complete string.
- you could use a counter initialized to zero and count one up for every one and one down for every zero, so you would have it zero on equal number of ones and zeros

Aditionally, if you get a really big amount of data (lots of lines and very long lines) it may make sense to check regulary if a line can be equal before you reach it's end (if you have 1001 ones on a 2000 charater line, you don't need to check any more and saved 999 itertions).